# Using Oracle Instant Client on ASP.NET. Getting ORA-12154 or 12545 Error

Tags: asp.net, oracle, ora-12514, instantclient, ora-12545

I have a web service that I have deployed and am using an Oracle Instant Client instance in the bin folder.  The problem is, no matter what connection string I use on a Testing Server, i get a ORA-12154 error or a ORA-12545 error.

Here's the connection string's I've tried:

```
//This one caused the ORA-12545 error:
<add key="oracleConnectString" value="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost.mydomain.com)(PORT=1574)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mysid)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));User Id=username;Password=password;" />

//These caused the ORA-12154 errors:
<add key="oracleConnectString" value="Data Source=username/password@//myhost.mydomain.com:1574/mysid;"/>
or
<add key="oracleConnectString" value="Data Source=myhost.mydomain.com:1574/mysid;User Id=username;Password=password;"/>
```

I've tried setting up TNS_ADMIN variables in the system and that did nothing for me.  Of course, everything works fine on my machine.  Just not on the deployed server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may have already solved this issue but did you do the following

1. Download the ODAC xcopy version

   - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html
2. Copy the following dll’s from the ODAC folder to either the bin (if web) or location of the exe file

   - oci.dll (Client Code Library)
   - ociw32.dll
   - Oracle.DataAccess.dll
   - orannzsbb11.dll (Security Library)
   - oraocci11.dll (OCCI Library)
   - oraociei11.dll (OCI Instant Client Data shared Library)
   - OraOps11w.dll
3. I created a blog post that walks though the steps along with a link to a sample application.

   - http://chadit.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/connect-from-net-to-oracle-without-installing-the-oracle-client/